# Transferring large arrays from server to client in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, json, gwt, data-transfer

I'm attempting to transfer a large two dimensional array (17955 X 3) from my server to the client using Asynchronous RPC calls. This is taking a very long period of time which is especially bad because the data is needed in order to initialize the application. I've read that using a JSON object might be faster, but I'm not sure how to do the conversion in Java as I'm pretty new to the language and GWT, and I don't know if the speed difference is significant. I also read somewhere that I can zip the data, but I only read that in a forum and I'm not sure if it's actually possible as I couldn't find information for it elsewhere. Is there any way to transfer large amounts of data from server to client? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/add-json-gwt-application.html) on adding **JSON** capabilities to GWT. In regards to compression [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114980/integrate-gzip-with-gwt) explains gzipping with GWT.

Also the size of your array is still very large even with the compression you may achieve with gzipping, which will vary depending on how much data is repeated in your array. You may want to consider logically breaking up the array in multiple RPC calls if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend revisiting your design if your application needs such a large amount of data to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

As other's pointed out, you **should** re-consider your design because even if you are able to solve the data transfer speed issue somehow you will likely find other issues waiting for you:

1. Processing large amount of data in the browser can be slow.
2. Lot of data means a lot of used-up memory

What you can think about is:

**Partitioning the data:**

How is your user going to cope with a lot of data. Your user will probably need some kind of user interface aid to be able to work with such a huge data. If you are going to use paging, tabs or other means to partition the data for user's consumption, why not load the data on demand. For example, you can load a single page of records if you are using a paging grid or you can load a single tab worth of records if you are going to use tabs. Similary, if you are going to allow filtering on the records, you can set a default filter after the load to keep the data to a minumum.

**Summarizing the data:**

You can also summarize the data on the server, if you are not going to show each row to the user. For example you can initially show summary for each group of records and let the user drill-down in a specific group