# Using GWT-RPC vs RequestFactory for passing large arrays

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I am building an application which retrieves data and parses it into a two-dimensional array object before sending it back to the client. The application then uses the data to create an image on HTML5 canvas. The array contains several thousand entries, and when I built the application using GWT-RPC, it worked properly, but it took too long to transfer the array to the client (several minutes).

I found this issue when searching for solutions: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=860

The last response was from a couple months ago, but there doesn't seem to be a conclusive answer to the best way to go about passing large arrays from server to client. Since deRPC is being deprecated (I have yet to actually try using it), is using requestfactory the only choice? It seems like requestFactory is supposed to be for accessing a database, and not for performing calculations and returning large results, and I haven't found an example where a request is made for a calculation and a result is passed back. Should I create a JSON object instead of an array in my current implementation and keep RPC or am I missing something when it comes to requestFactory?

Answer (score 4):

The issue you linked to is about slow speed of de-serialization on the client and not the data transfer speed. You should first measure the transfer speed using Firebug or similar tool and then subtract this time from total time of RPC call to find out how much time is spent during de-serialization. Roughly speaking, the breakup goes like this:

> Total RPC time = time-spent-on-server + network-time-in-out +
> deserialization-time

You should first find out which part is the real bottleneck, if it turns out to be the data transfer speed, you'll probably need to re-think your design. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142687/transferring-large-arrays-from-server-to-client-in-gwt/7148044#7148044) to a related question.

**EDIT:**

IMO, until you have calculated the above time breakup, you should put aside the question that whether JSON or another approach is right for you